# How to make canollis without a deep frier?

Tags: baking, deep-frying

I absolutely love cannolis but every recipe I see requires a deep frier. Is it possible to make them without one?

Answer (score 2):

The very nature of cannolis is that they are deep fried, but you don't need a fryer for that, a large pot, a half liter or so of neutral oil and a thermometer are all that you need. Like doughnuts, fried is the way to go, but they can be baked (if you must). Here's a sample recipe: [Baked Cannolis](http://diethood.com/cannoli-with-creamy-ricotta/).

Answer (score 0):

You can take a wok and put in significant amount of oil and let it heat sufficiently. You can test whether the oil is sufficiently high in temperature by dropping a little bit of salt in it. If you see an instant reaction then the oil is hot enough. After which you can drop in your canollis one at a time but don't put in too many canollis in a single batch as it could significantly reduce the tempeerature of oil and the canollis may come out to be undercooked and soggy.